# Error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have this code for a Shiny application. It works correctly when I click on "Run App" in Rstudio, but I want to publish this application on the web and I get the error: **Error in data$Product : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.**

How can I fix it? I have read the possible problems and I think that the error is when I create the function 'new' with a data.frame inside. I still don't understand why I get the error if when I make reference to new I always put **new()**.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# UI function
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Title
  titlePanel("SellOut Chile predictive model"),
  
  # Sidebar with inputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input for Date
      dateInput("date", "Date:", value = as.Date("2023-01-01")),
      
      # Input for Customers
      numericInput("customers", "Customers:", min = 6, max = 8, value = 7),
      
      # Input for Campaigns
      selectInput("campaigns", "Campaigns:", choices = c(0, 1), selected = 0),
      
      # Input for SellIn.UDS
      sliderInput("sellin", "SellIn.UDS:", 
                  min(0), 
                  max(60000), 
                  value = 20000),
      
      # Input for Product
      selectInput("product", "Product:", choices = unique(data$Product), selected = unique(data$Product)[1])
    ),
    
    # Main panel for outputs
    mainPanel(
      # Predicted SellOut
      h4("Predicted SellOut:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("prediction"),
      
      # Line plot output
      h4("Plot of Date vs SellOut:"),
      plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Server function
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Load data
  data <- read.csv("Dataset_Chile.csv", sep=";")
  
  # Convert the 'Campaigns' variable to a factor
  data$Campaigns <- as.factor(data$Campaigns)
  
  # Convert the 'Date' variable to days since the reference date
  data$Date <- as.numeric(as.Date(data$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")) - as.numeric(as.Date("01/01/2019", format="%m/%d/%Y"))
  
  # Define the linear regression model
  model <- lm(SellOut.UDS ~ Date + Product + SellIn.UDS + Customers + Campaigns, data=data)
  
  # Predict SellOut.UDS for new data
  new <- reactive({
    data.frame(Date=as.numeric(input$date - as.Date("2019-01-01")), Customers=input$customers, SellIn.UDS=input$sellin, Product=input$product, Campaigns=as.factor(input$campaigns))
  })
  output$prediction <- renderPrint({
    predict(model, newdata=new())
  })
  
  # Create a line plot of Date vs SellOut.UDS with lines colored by Product
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # Subset data to only include the selected Product
    subset_data <- subset(data, Product == input$product)
    
    # Predict SellOut.UDS for new data
    predicted_value <- predict(model, newdata=new())
    
    gg <- ggplot(subset_data, aes(Date, SellOut.UDS, group = Product, text = paste("SellIn.UDS: ", SellIn.UDS))) + 
      geom_line() + #aes(linetype = ifelse(SellOut.UDS == predicted_value, "predicted", "actual")) 
      xlab("Date") + 
      ylab("SellOut.UDS") +
      geom_point(data=new(), aes(x=Date, y=predicted_value), color="blue", size=2.5)
    
    # Create plotly object with hover functionality
    ggplotly(gg)
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your `data` object is local to your server function.  It is not available in your ui function.  Therefore, inside the ui function, R is attempting to access the built-in `data` function.  Hence the message.  You need to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput`  to do this sort of thing.  And avoid using reserved words as the names of your objects if you want more easily understood error messages.  Voting to close as  a typo.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen not quite:  `selectInput("product", "Product:", choices = unique(data$Product), selected = unique(data$Product)[1])` in the UI function.